# Web design for search string

Tags: search

I've notepad in which logs are present. I need to design a web page by which if some one paste their ticket number and click on "search" the logs for that ticket number should be displayed at the bottom.

I need some advice on how to do this and which is the right platform to do this.

Regards
Gopalan

Answer (score 0):

How big your logs?
You can use any platform that it can support regex(regular expression).
Or if it too big, I suggest you to use database

Comment: The logs are not big because the person can search only logs which are 1 month old. Maximum of 2000 lines. Du have any inbuilt scripts. Can i use PHP for this. If yes how ?

Comment: I don't know how is your log format but try this

<pre>
<code>
<?php
$search = 'assume this as ticket number';
$logs = readfile("logfile.txt");
if (preg_match("/".$search."/i", $log, $match)) {
    print_r($match);
} else {
    echo "A ticket was not found.";
}
?>
</code></pre>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$search = 'assume this as ticket number'; 
$logs = readfile("logfile.txt"); 
if (preg_match("/.*".$search.".*\n/i", $logs, $match)) 
{ 
   print_r($match); 
} 
else 
{ 
   echo "A ticket was not found."; 
} 
?>
```